# Facebook News Feed API

Tags: php, facebook

I've been searching everywhere. I've looked at 100 websites that don't really help.

I want to be able to show the users current news feed on a separate page.

I've read that "" will do the trick, the problem is I can't find the JS SDK Download or how to use it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Graph API call is: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=your_access_token_here

Here is the documenation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Comment: the access_token is what I don't understand. How do I get/generate it?

Comment: @Dremation The access token is generated via a Facebook app. Setup an app first and then use the app to get a token.